# How to restrict more than particular size upload in struts application?

Tags: java, struts2

I want to restrict more than 50mb size file upload features in whole application. Pls. help how to do it. I am using struts2 as a framework in Java.

Answer (score 3):

IF i understand your question right you want to restrict file upload size of any file being uploaded at any place in your application to <=50mb

you can defined it in either `struts.properties` file as

```
struts.multipart.maxSize=2097152
```

or you have the option to define it at struts.xml file

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1000000" />

</struts>
```

This setting defaults to approximately 2 megabytes and should be adjusted to the maximum size file (2 gigs max) that your will need the framework to receive.

can get more details at [File Upload configuration](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/file-upload.html)

hope this will help